# UISearchBar with background in the text

Tags: ios, background, ios4, uitextfield, uisearchbar

Do somebody know if it's possible change the UISearchBar's background? I mean to the inside (see image attached), i think that component is a UITextField.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it! I had to subclassing UISearchBar and override the layoutSubviews with:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    UITextField *searchField;
    NSUInteger numViews = [self.subviews count];
    for(int i = 0; i < numViews; i++) {
       if([[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        searchField = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
       }
    }
    if(!(searchField == nil)) {
       searchField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       [searchField setBackground: [UIImage imageNamed:@"SearchBarBackground.png"] ];
       [searchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
    }

    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

The image is a complete background image!

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan Naguin answer is also good but the single line answer for maintain code quality is

```
self.searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Searchbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: The method you are proposing is available from iOS5 and when the question was asked the latest version was iOS4

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an API that allows you to alter the background color. That component is a private subclass of a UITextField. It wouldn't be appropriate for anybody to rely on it even if we can achieve the effect using a hack.